# Question : When you say "beverages", does that implicitly mean alcohol? (Alcohol only)

Tags: word-usage

Thanks to native speaker, to my question.

My question is at the title, when you say only "beverages", would it **implicitly** mean (only) the alcohol?

Merriam Unabridged says,

> 1
>   :  liquid for drinking; especially :  such liquid other than water (such as tea, milk, fruit juice, beer) usually prepared (as by flavoring, heating, admixing) before being consumed
>
> 2
>   archaic :  any of several prepared drinks: such as
>   a :  a drink made by passing water through pressed grapes
>   b :  weak beer
>   c :  diluted cider
>
> 3
>   dialectal, British :  a drink or drink money especially when exacted from someone wearing manifestly new clothes

It includes other than alcohol. Could you kindly enlighten me?

I truly appreciate your support.

Comment: The definition you quote mentions _one_ alcoholic beverage (beer) and _three_ non-alcoholic ones!

Comment: @KateBunting Yeah....I'm sorry I can't get what you exactly try to mean...

Comment: Kate means  "Why do you need to ask if 'beverage' means 'alcoholic drink' when you have an authorative source that says it doesn't".  Its not clear why need to ask this question as your source contains the answer.

Comment: @JamesK Thanks for the clarification. May be I had some preconception that the word beverage means implicitly a bottle or can of alcohol drink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wiktionary defines [beverage](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/beverage) as:

> #### Noun
>
> **beverage** (*countable and uncountable*, *plural* **beverages**)
>
> 1. A liquid to consume; a drink, such as tea, coffee, liquor, beer, milk, juice, or soft drinks, usually excluding water.
>
>    - Thomson
>        He knew no **beverage** but the flowing stream.
> 2. (Britain, slang, archaic) (A gift of) drink money.

This is very similar to the Merriam Unabridged definition you found.

A beverage is basically a flavoured drink. Note Wiktionary excludes plain water, as does Merriam Unabridged.

**Native speakers will often think of alcoholic beverages, but not exclusively.** When I read your question I very quickly thought of tea as a non-alcoholic beverage.

Comment: Thanks! Especially here "When I read your question I very quickly thought of tea as a non-alcoholic beverage."

Comment: Certainly in British usage, if you want to unambiguously discuss alcoholic beverages, you call them 'alcoholic beverages'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey And if you want to unambiguously discuss nonalcoholic beverages, you call them "nonalcoholic beverages".

Comment: You can't argue with the dictionary definition. However, "beverage" is a somewhat formal term, and in casual conversation, it is often used to imply that alcohol is being at least suggested.

Comment: @JefftheChf Thank you for your comment! That's what I wanted to say in my question. **I don't know where my assumption or biased thought came from**, but personally when I hear the word "beverage", I  always think "Is it beer?".

Comment: I asked my family yesterday to think of an example of a beverage independently, then tell me. Two said tea, one coffee, one water, and one beer. I disqualified "water" since it's not a beverage. So 25% of the responses were alcoholic. I was surprised it was so low, but it backs up my point that beverages are not implicitly alcoholic.